# subgroup header for a kendo ui grid group header

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to group the data accordingly

```
Department A(Group)
    Class 1(Sub Group)
        Morning
        Afternoon
        Evening
    Class 2(Sub Group)
        Morning
        Afternoon
        Evening
Department B(Group)
```

Any possibilities in Kendo ui grid grouping...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is possible with Kendo UI Grid. Here is some sample code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: [ { 
      department: "A",
      "class": 1,
      type: "Evening"
    },{ 
      department: "A",
      "class": 2,
      type: "Morning"
    }, { 
      department: "B",
      "class": 1,
      type: "Evening"
    }, { 
      department: "B",
      "class": 2,
      type: "Morning"
    }],
    // group by "department" and "class"
    group: [ { field: "department" }, { field: "class" } ] 
  },
  columns: [ { field: "type" } ]
});
```

And a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ejalut/1/edit

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to accept my reply as the answer to your question.